# For not working properly on java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have the class Empresa and the class Funcionario, and when i'm trying to add a salary to a employee, it compile but don't work. here the codes:

Funcionario:

```
class Funcionario{
        String departamento;
        String dataEntrada;
        String rg;
        String nome;
        String ferias;
        double salario;

        void recebeAumento(double aumento){
                this.salario += aumento;
        }

        double calculaGanhoAnual(){
                this.salario = salario * 12;
                return salario;
        }

        void mostra(){
                System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
                System.out.println("Salário: " + this.salario);
                System.out.println("Departamento: " + this.departamento);
                System.out.println("RG: " + this.rg);
                System.out.println("Data de admissão: " + this.dataEntrada);
                System.out.println("Ganho anual: " + calculaGanhoAnual());
        }
}

class Empresa{
        String nome;
        String cnpj;
        Funcionario [] empregados = new Funcionario[10];

        void adiciona(Funcionario func){
                for(int i = 0; i < empregados.length; i++){/*i começa da posição 0 e tera o tamanho da
array empregados*/
                        if(empregados[i] == null){//se a posição estiver vazia
                                empregados[i] = func; /* a array recebe o valor de func que for adicionado pelo
metodo void*/
                                break;
                        }
                }
        }

        void mostraEmpregados(){
                Funcionario func = new Funcionario();
                for(int i = 0; i < this.empregados.length; i++){
                        System.out.println("Funcionário na posição: " + i);
                        System.out.println("Salário do funcionário: " +  func.salario);
                }
        }
}
```

And the Test class:

```
class TestaEmpresa{
        public static void main (String [] args){
                Empresa emp = new Empresa();
                emp.empregados = new Funcionario[10];
                Funcionario func = new Funcionario();
                for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                        func.salario = 1000.0 + i * 100;
                        emp.adiciona(func);
                }

                emp.mostraEmpregados();
        }
}
```

After running the test, i get the position of the array and the salary null, like this:

```
Funcionário na posição: 0
Salário do funcionário: 0.0
Funcionário na posição: 1
Salário do funcionário: 0.0
Funcionário na posição: 2
Salário do funcionário: 0.0
Funcionário na posição: 3
Salário do funcionário: 0.0
```

Comment: I would advise you never ever to write code in a language other than English (I mean identifiers, not string content), even if it uses latin alphabet as well. Especially when you ask for help with that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not retrieving elements from the array.

```
System.out.println("Salário do funcionário: " +  func.salario);
```

should be

```
System.out.println("Salário do funcionário: " +  this.empregados[i].salario);
```

In addition, you should probably make sure that `this.empregados[i]` is not null before accessing `this.empregados[i].salario`.

Comment: Thanks ! Worked great !

Answer (score 1):

the error is in your print method

```
   void mostraEmpregados(){
                Funcionario func = new Funcionario();
                for(int i = 0; i < this.empregados.length; i++){
                        System.out.println("Funcionário na posição: " + i);
                        System.out.println("Salário do funcionário: " +  func.salario);
                }
        }
```

change it for

```
System.out.println("Funcionário na posição: " + i);
                        System.out.println("Salário do funcionário: " +  this.empregados[i].salario);
```

you don't need that object Funcionario func = new Funcionario();